# HAProxy node automatically going into MAINT mode

Tags: haproxy

Some of my servers in haproxy randomly goes into maintenance mode. I am wondering how is this possible? Is there a configuration which can kick this in.

My assumption is that node can go into maintenance mode only through stats admin page or via `socat` comomand.

Comment: A server agent can do this.  Are you using `agent-check`?  Is there nothing in the logs?

Comment: We are not using any `agent-check`. The logs contain only normal status, going maint and out of it..

Comment: That should be impossible.  Maintenance mode, as far as I have ever understood it, is a hard override that disables traffic *and* health checks on a server.   Other than an agent, I believe you are correct -- it can only be toggled from the stats page or over the stats socket.  You might want to disable those and see what happens, next.